# How do I setup dual monitors with workspace on only one monitor?

Tags: unity, compiz, display-manager

I have dual monitors, one on the left and another on the right. I like to have VMWare Workstation opn the right hand monitor, full screen.

In Gnome3, when I switch workspaces the right side monitor keeps the same program open and workplace switching only affects the left side monitor.

How can I do the same thing in Unity on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Is having the 2nd screen running on a separate xserver an option?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible at the moment unfortunately. But an advanced multi-monitor support for is planned for Ubuntu 12.04. First previews were shown at the Ubuntu Developer Summit 1-2 weeks ago.